# C++ удалить нули из массива

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм

В первой строке задана длина исходного массива.
Во второй - сам массив.
Удалить из массива нули, вывести обновлённый массив. Если он оказался пустым, вывести "NO".

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void del (int *arr, int &i, int &n)
{
  n--;
  for (int j=i;j<n;j++)
  {
    arr[j] = arr[j+1];
  }
}
int main()
{
  int n;
  cin >> n;
  int *arr = new int[n];
  for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    cin >> arr[i];
  }
  for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    if (arr[i]==0) del(arr,i,n);
  }
  for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    cout << arr[i] << " ";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

При вводе

```
5
0 0 0 0 0
```

выводит

```
0 0
```

Comment: Нельзя идти по массиву и удалять из него элементы. Нужно создавать новый массив и сохранять в него измененный.

Comment: "_Если он оказался пустым, вывести "NO"._" - в коде это отсутствует.

Comment: Внезапно: использовать в этой задаче массивы совсем не нужно. Можно просто вывести входную последовательность чисел пропуская нули.

Comment: @VTT _вывести обновлённый массив_ суть задачи в работе с массивами

Comment: @Эникейщик верно, с этим смогу разобраться. проблема изложена в условии, выводит 2 нуля при заданном массиве

Comment: Потому что нельзя идти по массиву и удалять из него элементы. Тем самым остаются элементы, которые пропускаются и не проверяются, и именно они выводятся. Введите массив из 7 нулей, получите три (думаю). Введите массив из 25 нулей, получите больше десятка.

Comment: Просто на листике смоделируйте ввод из 4-5 элементов и пробегитесь по своему алгоритму и вы всё поймете

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Удаление на месте:

```
int removed = 0;
for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
   if (arr[i]==0)
      removed++;
   else
      arr[i-removed] = arr[i]; 
}
```

И в конце вывести начало массива длиной `n-removed`  (реального изменения длины задача вроде не требует)

Comment: Это хороший ответ,  потому я отметил как полезный, но  программа выдаст неожидаемый результат, если нули встречаются больше одного раза.

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan [ideone](https://ideone.com/YqPK9H)

Comment: Может быть и я ошибаюсь, просто нет времени проверять, но мне так показалось...

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan Ну ссылку с готовым кодом же недолго открыть

Comment: Точно, все верно, я ошибался(ну не знаю с чего мне так показалось)